# Busqueda con ajax y el cargado que sea en varios input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Soy nuevo en esto de ajax y no se mucho sobre este lenguaje, mi problema es que cuando yo hago una busqueda con ajax, siempre lo mando a otro archivo y lo que encuentra lo cargo en mi archivo donde hice la peticion, en un div pero siempre hago una busqueda de una tabla y que todo lo cargado sea en una tabla html pero ahora quiero que solo carguen varios datos en varios input text. Aqui viene mi pregunta, lo que quiero es hacer una peticion con ajax en mi archivo pero que el buscado lo cargue en varios input text ya no solo en un div como antes lo hacia, aqui esta mi avance:

-Input text que busca los datos en la bd: principal.php

```
<label for="dni">DNI:</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="dni">
<a id="BuscarPersona"><span class="fa fa-search"></span> Buscar Persona</a>
```

-Inputs donde quiero que carguen mis datos: principal.php

```
Primer Apellido:<input class="form-control" type="text" id="apellido1">
Segundo Apellido:<input class="form-control" type="text" id="apellido2">
Nombres:<input class="form-control" type="text" id="nombres">
Dni:<input class="form-control" type="text" id="dni2">
Edad:<input class="form-control" type="text" id="edad">

$('#BuscarPersona').on('click', function(){
var dni = $('#dni').val();
$.ajax({
      url: "/Distrito/Calles",
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", text: dni},
      success: function (response) {
            $("#apellido1").append(response);
           $("#apellido2").append(response);
           $("#nombres").append(response);
          $("#edad").append(response);
         $("#dni").append(response);
        }
    });
    });
```

-Archivo donde envio la consulta:Controller.php

```
public function aaa(Request $request){
$d=$request->text;
$data=Departamento::where('IdDni', $d);
$view = view('Distrito.Calle.cargado', compact('data'))>render();
return response()->json($view);
    }
```

-Archivo donde cargo datos: cargado.php

```
@foreach($datos as $d)
<td>{{$d->ape1}}</td>
<td>{{$d->ape2}}</td>
<td>{{$d->nom}}</td>
<td>{{$d->edad}}</td>
<td>{{$d->dni}}</td>
@endforeach
```

-Como hacer que eso datos se envien a mis input??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando vas a devolver un JSON, no es necesario cargar ninguna vista, y si tenemos en cuenta de que estas usando Laravel, casi no necesitas hacer nada. Una vez tienes el modelo del dato que buscas, puedes devolverlo sin problemas como un JSON.

Estos serian los cambios que tienes que hacer:

En la función que realizas en JS. Ahora recibirás un archivo JSON correctamente formateado, por lo tanto puedes acceder a los campos del modelo que enviaste.

```
$('#BuscarPersona').on('click', function(){
var dni = $('#dni').val();
$.ajax({
      url: "/Distrito/Calles",
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", text: dni},
      success: function (response) {
          $("#apellido1").val(response.ape1);
          $("#apellido2").val(response.ape2);
          $("#nombres").val(response.nom);
          $("#edad").val(response.edad);
          $("#dni").val(response.dni);
        }
    });
});
```

En cuanto en la parte de Laravel, quitamos la parte donde renderizas una vista. En su lugar, simplemente buscamos el modelo y lo devolvemos parseandolo a JSON.

```
public function aaa(Request $request){

  $d=$request->text;

  $data=Departamento::where('IdDni', $d)->first();

  return response()->json($data);

}
```

Y en cuanto a la vista, pues no la necesitamos.

Comment: amigo he visto por consola que carga los datos bien, pero no se pega en mi caja de texto...sabes cual es el error?

Comment: Disculpame, habia una errata en la obtención del modelo en Laravel, he añadido `->first()` en la respuesta, mira a ver si asi funciona

Comment: Listo ya salio, gracias por la ayuda! (y)

Comment: Disculpa amigo, una ultima pregunta...y si lo hago con una tabla que esta haciendo join...el get no lo pongo igual? o como seria? :s

Comment: Me temo que no entiendo bien del todo a que te refieres, pero si es algo diferente, creo que es mejor que hagas una nueva pregunta, no solo para que sea mas visible la respuesta al problema en concrete nuevo. Si no que más gente podrá ayudarte.

Comment: es lo mismo a la pregunta que acabo de hacer, solo que por ejemplo el Departamento::, lo haria con un join nada mas. Queria saber si se pone igual el first o no..bueno es mi duda

Comment: Ah, claro. No importa, el first lo que hace es obtener el primer dato que haya.

Comment: oh gracias man otra vez! Bueno eso era todo solo queria salirme de dudas para mas adelante cuando haga con join, muchas gracias!

Comment: Claro, aun asi te explico un poco para evitar lios en el futuro. Cuando haces `Departamento::where('IdDni', $d)` estas preparando la consulta, pero nunca la terminas de llamar. `first()`, `get()`, `count()`, etc. Ejecutan la consulta y te devuelven datos.

Comment: oh entiendo! Muchas gracias, ya veo que hay mas formas de hacer esa busqueda (y)